# Adding Bootstrap-sass on a Middleman template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, middleman, bootstrap-sass

I have added Twitter bootstrap-sass on my current Middleman template.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

All the CSS and stuffs are working well except for adding bootstrap javascripts.

I added this code on my layout.haml file

```
= require bootstrap
```

And then shows me this error,

```
NameError at /
undefined local variable or method `bootstrap' for #<Middleman::Application:0x25001556>
Ruby    d:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.2.1/lib/middleman-core/configuration.rb: in method_missing, line 78
Web     GET localhost/
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem your having is that you're not wrapping the `= require bootstrap` in sass within haml.

```
%style
  :sass
    = require bootstrap
```